# HTML editor with beginning and ending tag highlights for MAC

Tags: html, css, editor

I have used a variety of HTML editors on my Mac, including
-TacoEdit
-Textwrangler
-Aptana
  -a few others whose names escape me

But none of them are as great as Notepad++ that I have running on my PC (which is not available on Mac.) There is one feature of Notepad++ that I find utterly indispensable that I haven't seen in any other editor so far:

**It highlights the beginning and end of a tag.**

This has saved me SO many headaches when modifying a div-heavy site.

```
<div id="hooray"> 
In Notepad++ both of these element tags are highlighted. 
I LOVE IT.
</div>
```

(I guess its "run" feature is great too. So much better than anything I have on my Mac.) So I use my Windows PC when at work but wish I had a great editor for use on my Mac at home. Anybody know of one that has this beginning and end tag highlighting feature?

I prefer freeware but I am willing to invest some money into this if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 2):

Try editors like [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) or [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/). [Coda](http://panic.com/coda/) is great but probably more involved than what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In Aptana double clicking on the opening tag or the closing tag highlights respectively the closing and the opening tag.

You can also fold the code which is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is one of the best code editor for web developer.. Try it out if haven't tried it yet!